# Why R.color.xyz appear "gray", when i use in Canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

here is my color.xml

```
<color name="xyz">#507EC0</color>
<color name="abc">#27B0D0</color>
<color name="def">#A8CBE1</color>
```

and here goes the code inside onDraw()

```
Paint xyzPaint = new Paint();
         thisWeekTotalPaint.setColor(R.color.xyz);
         canvas.drawRect(30, 70, 200, 100, xyzPaint);
```

But it appears to be gray what ever the color i use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R.color.xyz` contains the Resource ID of the color, not the color itself, which you need for `setColor()`.

So you have to get the color from the Resources first:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.xyz);
yourPaint.setColor(color);
```